# How to specify Perl version for apache2 mod_cgi?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have installed additional versions of Perl on a Fedora 21 system.
On the PATH, my custom Perl (5.10.0) has priority over the distro's default Perl (5.18.4)

```
user$ perl -v
> This is perl, v5.10.0 built for x86_64-linux

root# perl -v
> This is perl, v5.10.0 built for x86_64-linux
```

However, when printing the Perl version in a script served by Apache, it appears to be using the "wrong" version:

```
5.018004
```

How can you direct Apache to use a specific version of Perl?

Comment: When using plain CGIs, the OS (through the #! line) is responsible for picking the interpreter. What's on the first line of your script ? and what is the output of `which perl` on the CLI ?

Comment: Yes - the shebang is to blame in that case. It points to /usr/bin/perl, which is the undesired version that shipped with the distro. Does mod_perl allow for overwriting this instruction?

Comment: Why are you trying to use an older version of Perl than the one that comes with your operating system? People usually have the opposite problem :-)

Comment: slightly ot, but to satisfy your curiosity: I inherited an old and ugly perl webservice and some of the code is now deprecated causing warnings/errors using modern perl. Thus, I need to use 5.10 until the offending parts of the code have been refactored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using plain CGIs, the OS (through the #! line) is responsible for picking the interpreter. As we have established, the shebang was pointing to the wrong version of the interpreter.

The easiest way is to edit it. If you need the same script to work with two different perl versions depending on the call context, you can use something like `#!/usr/bin/env perl` in the shebang to have it respect the environment, then change the `PATH` variable for apache.

If you cannot edit the shebang, there is the option of going through `mod_perl` (make sure you compile it against the desired version) if you don't mind using this specific version for the whole webserver.

Another way would be to run the webserver within some kind of container (chroot, lxc, docker, or just using mount namespaces) so that your `/usr/bin/perl` points to some other version of the interpreter.